# Servicestack Gateway.Send does not work with POST

Tags: servicestack

I have this service method

```
  public async Task Post(DeviceEndpointInsertTemp request)
        {
            //Some AYNC Code
         }
```

I call it like this

```
          var model = new DeviceEndpointInsertTemp() {DeviceNumber = deviceID, IOEndpointList = list, EventGridPostDateTime = postTime};
                var task = Gateway.SendAsync(model);
                await task; //wait for response
```

I get this error

```
{"Could not find method named Put(DeviceEndpointInsertTemp) or Any(DeviceEndpointInsertTemp) on Service IntegrationService"}
```

UNTIL I change the POST to ANY

```
public async Task ANY(DeviceEndpointInsertTemp request)
    {
        //Some AYNC Code
     }
```

Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in the [Service Gateway Docs](https://docs.servicestack.net/service-gateway):

Naked Request DTO’s without annotations are sent as a **POST** but alternative Verbs are also supported by annotating Request DTO’s with [HTTP Verb Interface Markers](https://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client#http-verb-interface-markers) where Request DTO’s containing `IGet`, `IPut`, etc. are sent using the typed Verb API, e.g:

```
[Route("/customers/{Id}")]
public class GetCustomer : IGet, IReturn<Customer>
{
    public int Id { get; set ;}
}
```

So if you want to send your Service Gateway to send a **PUT** Request your Request DTO needs to implement the appropriate [HTTP Verb Interface Marker](https://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client#http-verb-interface-markers), e.g:

```
public class DeviceEndpointInsertTemp : IPut, IReturn<TheResponse>
{
  //...
}
```